# vb.net Unhandled Exception in the Designer after Moving Controls Around the Form During Design Time

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, controls, designer, unhandled-exception

I can drop controls onto my form from my toolbox with no problem, but if I drag and drop the control around the form I get this error message:

```
"The control System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView has thrown an unhandled exception in the designer and has been disabled.

Exception:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: child"
```

And it paints an error image on the control.  This error is only happening on one of my forms and everything runs the way it should when I debug.  It's not a huge problem but it gets rather annoying when every time I move any control around on this particular form, I get this error and it paints an error image across the control.  Here is the message that the error image displays on the control:

```
"System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: child
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndexInternal(Control child, Int32 newIndex)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex(Control child, Int32 newIndex)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Design.EventManager.Reparent(ShapeContainer shCon)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowersPacks.Design.EventManager.OnEndDrag(Object sender, BehaviorDragDropEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.OnEndDrag(BehaviorDragDropEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.DoDragDrop(DropSourceBehavior dropSourceBehavior)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.OnMouseDragMove(Int32 x, Int32 y)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message& m)"
```

Thanks and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First time I've seen this go wrong, this designer is pretty solid.  It sure is scrambled all to hell, looks like you are moving a Shape control but it is complaining about a DataGridView.  Some of your own code runs at design time as well, always a good way to have random stuff going wrong.

Comment: I can't find anything different between this form and my other forms.  This form had been working correctly several days ago and yesterday out of the blue, I move a control to a different location on the form and it throws this error and have been getting this same error every time I move any other control.

Comment: Hans, I'm glad you said something about the shape control, I had one shape control on my form and once I removed it, I no longer get the error when moving controls around on the form.  Still weird because I use those controls all the time and have never had this problem.